# Preventing SwipeMenuListView to open on some Item in the ListView

Tags: android

i am using SwipeMenuListView from Github which working fine
But according to requirement of the application i have to show the divider of the list View through out the screen
For this i used some empty (dummy) data and showed it in the List View
The problem raised here because the dummy data also Swipe
i want not to be able to swipe on the dummy data
i also tried to override the on touch Event of the Super class like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
if((notesCursor.getCount()-1)<position){
        return true;  
//event tried retun flase;
    }
return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

it works for the item in the list view from the data base but when i swipe on the dummy data the program hang (not crash but i am not able to click any where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirement as you.

I tried to create different menus for divider items and non-divider items.

```
SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {
    @Override
    public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
        // do not create menu if item is a divider
        if (menu.getViewType() != DIVIDER) {
            SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9, 0x3F, 0x25)));
            deleteItem.setWidth(CommonUtil.dp2px(70, getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
            deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);
            menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
        }
    }
};
```

Please refer to [baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView#create-different-menu)
.